# Get the whole string from a String array if the string contains a substring

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

I have a string array for example:

```
string[] myStrings = {"I want to take this string","This is not interesting"}
```

I want to check the string array if it contains a value and then return the entire string that contains it.

Example:

```
var index = Array.FindIndex(stringArray, x => x == stringArray.Contains("want"));
```

After this I want to return the string: `I want to take this string` since this contains the keyword I searched for.

How can I archieve this result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use LINQ instead:

```
IEnumerable<string> occurences = stringArray.Where(s => s.Contains("want"));
```

In `occurences` you have the complete strings of *all* occurences which did match. You can do `FirstOrDefault` on it if you are just interested in the first hit.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`Array.FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy(v=vs.110).aspx) as you've already tried, but then use this:

```
int index = Array.FindIndex(myStrings, str => str.Contains("want"));
string desired = index >= 0 ? myStrings[index] : null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
myStrings.FirstOrDefault(str => str.Contains("want"));
```

This will return the first string that contains `want` or `null` if it was not found. If you want a List of all the strings that contain `want` then replace `FirstOrDefault` with `Where`

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string GetStringContent()
{
    string[] myStrings = { "I want to take this string", "This is not interesting" };
    string strContent=string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < myStrings.Length; i++)
    {
        if (myStrings[i].Contains("want"))
        {
           return  myStrings[i];
        }
    }
    return strContent;
}
```

Try This... It will return first string  if it contains 'want'.

Comment: Instead of keep on looping, you could simply return or break if you are only interested in the first (or last in your case).